# RuntimeException in doInBackground( )

Tags: android, android-asynctask, crash-reports

I keep getting this error in crash report from user devices but works well in my device in release as well as debug build.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run (AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker   (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:  at android.os.Looper.prepare(Looper.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.prepare (Looper.java:97)
at com.wolf.nniroula.creditrecorder.activity.SplashScreen$InitData.doInBackground (SplashScreen.java)
or.onPostExecute (SplashScreen.java)
at com.wolf.nniroula.creditrecorder.activity.SplashScreen$InitData.doInBackground (SplashScreen.java)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
```

And here is the `InitData()` class

```
public class InitData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == null)
            Looper.prepare();
        SettingManager.getInstance();
        RecordManager.getInstance(CreditApplication.getAppContext());
        CreditUtil.init(CreditApplication.getAppContext());
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        versionText.setText(CreditUtil.getCurrentVersion());
        loadingText.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        loadDataCompleted = true;
        if (loadDataCompleted && showAnimationCompleted && !activityStarted) {
            activityStarted = true;
            startActivity(new Intent(mContext, HomeActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: I think your null check on `myLooper` has a typo. You should check for `!= null`

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thanks, I'll check that.

Comment: No that code is correct, reading the docs anyway, and it would be a NPE surely instead, or illegalstateexception? Other than the last line in the doInBackground block most of what you are doing seems irrelevant, unless you are using it to instantiate/initialise expensive Singletons?

Comment: @MarkKeen Yeah, I'm trying to initialize some Singletons from my SplashScreen Activity.